# Flatten a nested dict structure into a dataset

Tags: python, data-structures, dataset

For some post-processing, I need to flatten a structure like this

```
{'foo': {
          'cat': {'name': 'Hodor',  'age': 7},
          'dog': {'name': 'Mordor', 'age': 5}},
 'bar': { 'rat': {'name': 'Izidor', 'age': 3}}
}
```

into this dataset:

```
[{'foobar': 'foo', 'animal': 'dog', 'name': 'Mordor', 'age': 5},
 {'foobar': 'foo', 'animal': 'cat', 'name': 'Hodor',  'age': 7},
 {'foobar': 'bar', 'animal': 'rat', 'name': 'Izidor', 'age': 3}]
```

So I wrote this function:

```
def flatten(data, primary_keys):
    out = []
    keys = copy.copy(primary_keys)
    keys.reverse()
    def visit(node, primary_values, prim):
        if len(prim):
            p = prim.pop()
            for key, child in node.iteritems():
                primary_values[p] = key
                visit(child, primary_values, copy.copy(prim))
        else:
            new = copy.copy(node)
            new.update(primary_values)
            out.append(new)
    visit(data, { }, keys)
    return out

out = flatten(a, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

I was not really satisfied because I have to use `copy.copy` to protect my inputs. Obviously, when using `flatten` one does not want the inputs be altered.

Then I thought about one alternative that uses more global variables (at least global to `flatten`) and uses an index instead of directly passing `primary_keys` to `visit`. However, this does not really help me to get rid of the ugly initial copy:

```
    keys = copy.copy(primary_keys)
    keys.reverse()
```

So here is my final version:

```
def flatten(data, keys):
    data = copy.copy(data)
    keys = copy.copy(keys)
    keys.reverse()
    out = []
    values = {}
    def visit(node, id):
        if id:
            id -= 1
            for key, child in node.iteritems():
               values[keys[id]] = key
               visit(child, id)
        else:
            node.update(values)
            out.append(node)
    visit(data, len(keys))
    return out
```

Is there a better implementation (that can avoid the use of `copy.copy`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: modified to account for variable dictionary depth.

By using the `merge` function from my previous answer (below), you can avoid calling `update` which modifies the caller. There is then no need to copy the dictionary first.

```
def flatten(data, keys):
    out = []
    values = {}
    def visit(node, id):
        if id:
            id -= 1
            for key, child in node.items():
               values[keys[id]] = key
               visit(child, id)
        else:
            out.append(merge(node, values))  # use merge instead of update
    visit(data, len(keys))
    return out
```

One thing I don't understand is why you need to protect the `keys` input. I don't see them being modified anywhere.

---

**Previous answer**

How about list comprehension?

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    return dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))

[[merge({'foobar': key, 'animal': sub_key}, sub_sub_dict) 
    for sub_key, sub_sub_dict in sub_dict.items()] 
        for key, sub_dict in a.items()]
```

The tricky part was merging the dictionaries without using `update` (which returns `None`).

Comment: Your solution works with my sample, but not with my real data which have much more layers. I need a recursive algorithm here.